# Read lines from .txt and if the first and last char equals to X and Y, add some text after that string

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

i'm trying to solve a problem that consists in:

1. open a .txt input file
2. `readlines` of that .txt
3. store the lines values in a `list`
4. check `if lin.startswith("2") and lin.endswith("|")`
5. if it's true, then `lin2 = lin + "ISENTO"`
6. write the edited lines to an output .txt file

Here's what i got until now...

```
def editTxt():
    #open .txt file and read the lines  
    filename = askopenfilename(filetypes=[("Text files","*.txt"), ("Text files","*.TXT")])
    infile = open(filename, 'r')
    infile.read()

    #save each line in a list called "linhas" outside the editTxt function
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        linhas = f.readlines()

    #create the output file
    outfile = open(filename + "_edit.txt", 'w')

    #checking the condition and writing the edited lines
    for linha in linhas:
        if linha.startswith("2") and linha.endswith("|"):
            linha = linha + "ISENTO"
        outfile.write(linha)

    #close files
    outfile.close()
    infile.close()
```

The problem is that my output file is exactly equals my input file...

i've already tried to use `if linha[0] == "2" and linha[len(linha)-1] == "|"`

but then i figured it out that the module `f.readlines()` just add `\n` after my string...
so i tried with `if linha[0] == "2" and linha[len(linha)-3] == "|"`

but i didn't worked too...

some guys told me that i should use the replace function.. but i couldn't figure how

> The real file example:
>
> **lin1:** 10|1,00|55591283000185|02/03/2015|31/03/2015
>
> **lin2:** 20|I||VENDA|0|9977|02/03/2015 00:00:00|02/03/2015 11:48:00|1|5102|||07786273000152|OBSERVE SEGURANCA LTDA|RUA
>   MARINGA,|2150||BOA VISTA|RIBEIRAO PRETO|SP|14025560||39121530|
>
> **lin3:** 30|1103|DAT 05MM - 5.102||PC|1,0000|19,9000|19,90|090|0,00|0,00|0,00

I just need to change the lin2, because it starts with "2" and ends with "|"

> what i need after running the editTxt function:
>
> **lin2:** 20|I||VENDA|0|9977|02/03/2015 00:00:00|02/03/2015 11:48:00|1|5102|||07786273000152|OBSERVE SEGURANCA LTDA|RUA
>   MARINGA,|2150||BOA VISTA|RIBEIRAO PRETO|SP|14025560||39121530|ISENTO

please python experts, show me an easier way to do this with another code or preferably explaining to me whats wrong with mine..

thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were very close with your last attempt

The '\n' line terminator is not literally the characters '\' and 'n'. It's a special character that is represented, for convenience by '\n'. So it's only one character in your string not two.

Hopefully, that should give you enough of a hint to figure out how to change your code :)

Comment: i've already tried to use
 
`for linha in linhas:
  if linha[0] == "2" and linha[len(linha)-1] == "|":
   linha = linha + "ISENTO"
  outfile.write(linha)`

but that didn't worked... :(

Comment: len(linha)-2, gotta skip the newline character.

Comment: i already tried with linha.endswith("|"), linha[len(linha)-1], -2 and -3.... none of these worked.
they dont write ISENTO at the end of the sentence, so my output file is excatly the same as the input file

Comment: try `rstrip`ing the "\n" then  checking the beginning and end for the relevant characters.